# Как реализовать пункт с подпунктами в Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. У меня есть одна задача и я пока не знаю как ее решить. В приложении  мне нужно реализовать следующее: есть активити, которая отображает список, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы у каждого пункта были еще подпункты, причем они добавляются пользователем, их может вообще не быть - по желанию пользователя.А еще и пункт и подпункт можно отмечать галочками. До этого у меня был просто списочек ListView, выводился из базы.

Comment: [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Я так поняла, что там фиксированное количество подпунктов, нет?..

Comment: @Аля нет, количество подпунктов может быть разное